# Swift / OS X : Transform is not available

Tags: swift, transform

When developing for iOS I can use the transform command with success but when developing for OS X transform is not available .. Here is the line i am having problem with:

```
mapView.viewForAnnotation(myAnnotation).transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(mapView.transform, 48)
```

PS: I did import everything (CoreGraphics, QuartzCore) still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

NSView does not have a transform property like UIView does.

You will have to set the wantsLayer flag for the view, and then use the view's layer's CATransform3D property.

Comment: Yes it is. Add your code to your original question.

Comment: I have found a very easy way.. instead of transform you can use boundsRotation which does exactly the same thing in my case.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about that property. You should post that as an answer to your own question and accept it.